Searching for all local minima in a mathematical optimization algorithm
I am writing a C# application that runs a physics simulation based on a CAD model and user inputs. It uses a mathematical optimization library (NLoptNet) to find stable-state solutions to various user-defined conditions by converging on a minima. For example: find a position of a floating object (immersion depth and angles) at which it is stable (doesn't tip over).
Sometimes user may need to find all the minima, so they can identify how many there are, and choose a specific one as a desired solution for closer inspection. In that floating object example, suppose it is a motor boat, and it might be most stable right side up (global minima), but the user actually wants to inspect a position where it is stable in the upside down position (also a minima, but not the global one). In this example it is very obvious that there are just 2 minimas, but in other cases there might be some other weird angles of stability that are difficult to identify by the user.
So, I am trying to come up with an algorithm that would probe the model, identify local minima, converge on each one of them, and finally return them in a list. Of course, there can be no 100% guarantee that it identified all the minima, but the reliability increases with the number of initial probe points.
I was thinking of doing the "probing" by simply iterating through initial values of control variables and running one of the local minima optimization algorithm starting from them, but the problem is that the algorithm may lock on to a minima that was already found before, and waste a lot of cycles chasing it down again. I can't think of any way to identify this early and skip over to the next probe point.
I suspect that it should be somehow possible to utilize one of the NLopt global optimization algorithms, since by definition it must find most of the minimas and compare them, but I also can't figure out a specific workflow to achieve that.
Can you suggest some ideas?

@Brannon, since NLoptNet is your work, I was thinking, if you have the time, could you please take a look at this question and let me know if you have any ideas?

One approach that comes to mind is to adjust the objective function by adding penalties for proximity to each known local minimum. After each new minimum is located, another penalty term gets added to the objective. Since a local min for the penalized objective is not necessarily a local min for the original objective, you might want to run the original (penalty-free) model starting at the new candidate to refine it. I said "not necessarily" because this depends on your choice of penalty function. If the penalty drops to zero quickly enough as you move away from the corresponding known minimum, refinement might be unnecessary.

That is an interesting idea, but how do I determine the size of the penaltized area around the already found minima to make this work? If the size is too small, an artificial minima "trench" will form around the penalized minima that the optimizer will fall into. If the penalty is too high, it will reach other true minima and distort them.

The best answer I can give to that is trial and error. It is indeed a concern. The distortion is one reason I suggested a "refinement" step after finding a candidate. Note that any type of "neighborhood exclusion" approach is going to face the same concern -- too small an exclusion area and the solver may "fall into the well" again, too large and the solver may be scared away from other optima.
